# Remote function calling with paramerters

Tags: php, curl

I am using this function for calling method from one server to another in PHP.

```
function get_url($request_url) {
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
}

$request_url = 'http://second-server-address/listening_page.php?function=somefunction';
$response = get_url($request_url);
```

Here I am giving a URL with function name. The question is what if the function receives few parameters? How would we pass parameters to the method on another server using CURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
$request_url = 'http://second-server-address/listening_page.php?function=somefunction&funcParam1=val&funcParam2.val
```

Use these passed parameters in your function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass parameter as post request then try this.

```
function post_to_url($url, $data) {
$fields = '';
foreach($data as $key => $value) { 
  $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
}
rtrim($fields, '&');

$post = curl_init();

curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($post);

curl_close($post);
}

$data = array(
  "name" => "c.bavota",
  "website" => "http://bavotasan.com",
  "twitterID" => "bavotasan"
);

post_to_url("http://yoursite.com/post-to-page.php", $data);
```